# List out-of-date branches with `repo forall`

Tags: git, repo

Just to clarify, this is about [Android Repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html).

I would like to be able to compare my working directory against an arbitrary remote branch using `repo forall` to see if there are any changes that I need to pull from that branch.

This is the closest I've gotten so far:

```
repo forall -p -c "git rev-list HEAD..origin/branchname --count"
```

That command will print the number of commits the working copy is behind origin/branchname for each git project. I would like to make it better by:

- Ignoring branches that are already up-to-date. Sometimes a remote branch contains an empty merge commit or something that will report a nonzero number with the above command, but the branch does not actually contain any new code.
- Printing no output for branches that are up-to-date. I really only care about branches that aren't up-to-date. I don't need to see a bunch of 0's. `repo forall` will not print output if I can make the git command not print output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
repo forall -p -c "if [[ `git diff HEAD origin/branchname` ]]; then git rev-list HEAD..origin/branchname --count; fi"
```

Comment: The command seems to do exactly what I want, but I can't get it to work with repo forall: `bash: /home/mkasberg/bin/repo: Argument list too long`

Comment: Fixed it: `repo forall -p -c "git diff --quiet HEAD origin/branchname || git rev-list HEAD..origin/branchname --count"`